# Load data into CActiveForm dropDownList using ajax

Tags: jquery, yii

I want to load data into CActiveForm dropDownList using ajax. I have searched in the forums and found that yiisupports dependent dropdown. But I don't want to use dependent dropdown. I have only one dropdown and I want to load data into that dropdown on an event. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to use load data into dropDown on an event then it is also dependent dropDown. On which event do you want to populate data in DropDown?

Comment: @RafayZiaMir  I am using jquery combogrid plugin. So on selecting an item in the combogrid, I want to load data into the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to load data into dropdownlist using the method described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/14200-updating-dropdownlist-after-writing-in-textfield/page__p__70318__hl__drop+down+ajax#entry70318)